# Run time error C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a simple program involving large data sets and analyzing them. The program is quite simple and it gives no error in compilation. however while running it just stops working. I'm an amateur programmer with only basic C knowledge. I'm guessing here that somehow some datatype limit is being exceeded because of the large data. Any help is appreciated !
here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    n=193704;
    // original data set arrays 
    double xcor[193706],ycor[193706],zcor[193706],decibel[193706],frequency[193706],node[193706]; 

    // new data set arrays
    double xcor1[193706], ycor1[193706], zcor1[193706], decibel1[193706], frequency1[193706], node1[193706];

    // equating all values of modified arrays to zero for future comparison

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        xcor1[i]=0;
        ycor1[i]=0;
        zcor1[i]=0;
        decibel1[i]=0;
        frequency1[i]=0;
        node1[i]=0;
    }


    //FILE POINTERS DEFINED HERE
    FILE *acdb, *freq, *nodes, *xcord, *ycord, *zcord, *hearfreq, *heardb, *hearx, *heary, *hearz ;
    acdb=(fopen("acousticdb.txt","r"));
    freq=(fopen("frequency.txt","r"));
    nodes=(fopen("node.txt","r"));
    xcord=(fopen("xcor.txt","r"));
    ycord=(fopen("ycor.txt","r"));
    zcord=(fopen("zcor.txt","r"));
    hearfreq=(fopen("hearingrangefrequency.txt","w"));
    heardb=(fopen("hearingrangedecibel.txt","w"));
    hearx=(fopen("hearing-x.txt","w"));
    heary=(fopen("hearing-y.txt","w"));
    hearz=(fopen("hearing-z.txt","w"));



    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        fscanf(acdb, "%lf", &decibel[i]);
        fscanf(freq, "%lf", &frequency[i]);
        fscanf(nodes, "%lf", &node[i]);
        fscanf(xcord, "%lf", &xcor[i]);
        fscanf(ycord, "%lf", &ycor[i]);
        fscanf(zcord, "%lf", &zcor[i]);
    }
    fclose(acdb);
    fclose(freq);
    fclose(nodes);
    fclose(xcord);
    fclose(ycord);
    fclose(zcord);

    // checking frequecy within hearing range
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(frequency[i]<20000 && frequency[i]>20 )
        {
            xcor[i]=xcor1[i];
            ycor[i]=ycor1[i];
            zcor[i]=zcor1[i];
            decibel[i]=decibel1[i];
            frequency[i]=frequency1[i];
            node[i]=node1[i];
        }
    }

    //wiriting values in text file
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fprintf(hearfreq," %lf \n", frequency1[i]);
        fprintf(heardb," %lf \n", decibel1[i]);
        fprintf(hearx," %lf \n", xcor1[i]);
        fprintf(heary," %lf \n", ycor1[i]);
        fprintf(hearz," %lf \n", zcor1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error are you getting?

Comment: And why exactly do you not allocate `double xcor1[193706]` dynamically? Do you really want to save 1m+ double values on the stack?

Comment: Try running it with 1000 values first. `double xcor[1000]` and `n=1000`. If there is no runtime error, then you are facing memory issues.

Comment: You probably run out of stack space - welcome to "Stack Overflow"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably run out of stack space. But if I look at the code then there is no need to first read all the data into arrays: all calculations are on a single index (`i`) and so you can just read one data item from each file, check if they are within hearing frequency and write them out:

```
int main()
{
    int i, n=193704;
    // original data set arrays 
    double xcor,ycor,zcor,decibel,frequency,node; 
    // new data set arrays
    double xcor1, ycor1, zcor1, decibel1, frequency1, node1;
    //FILE POINTERS DEFINED HERE
    FILE *acdb, *freq, *nodes, *xcord, *ycord, *zcord, *hearfreq, *heardb, *hearx, *heary, *hearz ;

    acdb=(fopen("acousticdb.txt","r"));
    freq=(fopen("frequency.txt","r"));
    nodes=(fopen("node.txt","r"));
    xcord=(fopen("xcor.txt","r"));
    ycord=(fopen("ycor.txt","r"));
    zcord=(fopen("zcor.txt","r"));
    hearfreq=(fopen("hearingrangefrequency.txt","w"));
    heardb=(fopen("hearingrangedecibel.txt","w"));
    hearx=(fopen("hearing-x.txt","w"));
    heary=(fopen("hearing-y.txt","w"));
    hearz=(fopen("hearing-z.txt","w"));

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        fscanf(acdb, "%lf", &decibel);
        fscanf(freq, "%lf", &frequency);
        fscanf(nodes, "%lf", &node);
        fscanf(xcord, "%lf", &xcor);
        fscanf(ycord, "%lf", &ycor);
        fscanf(zcord, "%lf", &zcor);

        // checking frequecy within hearing range
        if(frequency<20000 && frequency>20 )
        {
            xcor=xcor1;
            ycor=ycor1;
            zcor=zcor1;
            decibel=decibel1;
            frequency=frequency1;
            node=node1;
        }
        else xcor1= ycor1= zcor1= decibel1= frequency1= node1= 0.0;

        //wiriting values in text file
        fprintf(hearfreq," %lf \n", frequency1);
        fprintf(heardb," %lf \n", decibel1);
        fprintf(hearx," %lf \n", xcor1);
        fprintf(heary," %lf \n", ycor1);
        fprintf(hearz," %lf \n", zcor1);
    }
    fclose(acdb);
    fclose(freq);
    fclose(nodes);
    fclose(xcord);
    fclose(ycord);
    fclose(zcord);
    // don't forget to close these
    fclose(hearfreq);
    fclose(heardb);
    fclose(hearx);
    fclose(heary);
    fclose(hearz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this smarter way. I guess there was never the need for loading huge data files in huge arrays.
 But after running this program it still doesn't give me the correct result. the new files generated has all values as zero. but it shouldn't be like that. after checking whether the given frequency value is within range it should just note the values of other corresponding parameters and save it in separate text files.

Comment: If everything is zero, then probably the `fscanf` fails. You should check the return value of the fscanf calls; it should be 1. The logic of my solution is identical to your original. Any logic errors are yours.

Comment: Hey i managed it. thanks for your help !!! really liked your way to skip your way around arrays.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. I see you are new to the site. A good way to thank a contributor is to click on the up-arrow at the beginning of the solution. This gives the contributor "reputation points". To accept the solution, click on the number between the up and down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare arrays like this

```
double xcor1[193706];
```

without dynamic memory allocation using `malloc()` or similar, you are reserving that space on the stack. Considering you are doing more then 1 million double elements on your stack, it is probably overflowing. You have a literal stack overflow.

Quips aside, use dynamic memory allocation for such big arrays. 
It works like this:

```
double* xcor1 = malloc(sizeof(double) * 193706) ;
```

And when you're all done with it, don't forget to free it, too.

```
free(xcor1);
```

Ofcourse, with your code, you can also just not use arrays alltogether and not save the data in between, and instead use single variables for your operations.